# Why we use ./ instead of just typing its name when running the script?

Tags: bash, scripts

when we run a normal command we just type the name of it but why we use ./ instead of just typing its name when running the script?

Answer (score 3):

When you run a shellscript or some other program that is in the current directory, you use

```
./scriptname
```

because **`.`** denotes the current directory.

When a shellscript or some other program is in a directory in PATH, it is enough with its name for the system to find it,

```
program-in-path
```

You can watch PATH with

```
echo $PATH
```

You can put own programs into `~/bin` (create your own 'bin' and put your own programs there) and it will be found by you, or put it into `/usr/local/bin` and it will be found by all users.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: you could also put `.` into the `$PATH` so you never have to type `./` again, not in any directory. However, that is a security vulnerability (someone could write a malicious program called `ls` and put it in your favourite path, where it was just waiting for you to execute it) so don't do that.