# How to make ubuntu know a terminal command for the entire machine?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, automation

I have a lot of projects. And for each project, I have two files in them: `setup` and `serve`.

Each developer follows these simple three steps to start coding:

1. `git clone ...`
2. `./setup`
3. `./serve`

The problem is that `./setup` is not easy to type. And since this is a microservice architecture with a lot of repositories, `./setup` and `./serve` would be used frequently.

How can I make **ubuntu** understand that any time I write `setup` anywhere I mean *there is a file called `setup` and you should run it*.

This way developers would only configure their machines once, and then start coding using `clone,setup,serve` paradigm.

Comment: There are a number of ways; `/usr/local/bin` for example is a directory searched by all users on the system, thus files (or shortcuts) placed in that directory will be found and run, as will anywhere in $PATH...   If you're using commands that different products use (setup, clone are commands used by other software too) you'll have to be careful though...  (you can also make $PWD part of your path.. but there are risks with that which is why it's not default!)

Comment: There is a bit of explanation of PATH for executable files (binary programs, shellscripts etc) at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344556/why-we-use-instead-of-just-typing-its-name-when-running-the-script/) and links from it.